# How to get Stack Overflow notifications on browser or mobile device

Tags: discussion, notifications

I am using Stack Overflow to give and get answers to questions, but I have to refresh the page to check Stack Overflow notifications.

Is there a way to get Stack Overflow notifications on mobile or web browser?